# Add iPhone Sharing Button

Tags: iphone, uiactionsheet, sharing

I've gotten Tweet sheets to appear in my app, but I'd like to spawn them only when a user presses the particular "Tweet" button in a UIActionSheet.

Currently, my UIActionSheet is being shown in the main view after the user presses a Rounded Rect Button. I would like to change this button to be Apple's "standard" share method, which is using the button with the square image and the arrow jumping out of it, as shown below

[image]

Where could I find the image for the button to do this, or is the button already built into XCode?

I hope I'm being clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: it is a build-in icon in the iOS, it is the *Action* button. this image is available for the `UIBarButtonItem`, under the `UIBarButtonSystemItemAction` identifier. if you need that image separately, you have to create it for yourself somehow.

Comment: How is this related to Xcode?

Comment: is your button in a toolbar or navigationbar, or is it just in the view somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to just create toolbar item with **Bar Button Item**. In Attributes Inpector choose **'Action'** type of your button.

[image]

Attach selector/method from your rounded rect button to this button.

HTH!